# Any way I can get SoX to just print the amplitude values from a wav file?

Tags: c++, sox

I'm using a simple line of code:

```
sox vocal2.wav -t dat vocal2.dat
```

via SoX to convert a wav file to a text file showing the amplitude values at certain time positions. The output data also has a header showing sample rate and number of channels.

I need to use the amplitude data in a C++ program to determine the pitch of the input, but it's annoying to have to convert the file, drag the data into Excel, copy one column, save it to a new .txt file and then work with it.

Is there a way I can tell SoX to JUST output the amplitude in the converted file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the data specifically for use in C++, it's very easy to use something like [Libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/).  It's a pretty mature C library, but comes with a convenient C++ wrapper (sndfile.hh).

Here's example usage lifted from something I wrote recently where I needed easy access to audio data.

```
std::string infile_name = "/path/to/vocal2.wav";

// Open input file.
SndfileHandle infile_handle( infile_name );
if( !infile_handle || infile_handle.error() != 0 )
{
    std::cerr << "Unable to read " << infile_name << std::endl;
    std::cerr << infile_handle.strError() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

// Show file stats
int64_t in_frames = infile_handle.frames();
int in_channels = infile_handle.channels();
int in_samplerate = infile_handle.samplerate();
std::cerr << "Input file: " << infile_name << std::endl;
std::cerr << " * Frames      : " << std::setw(6) << in_frames << std::endl;
std::cerr << " * Channels    : " << std::setw(6) << in_channels << std::endl;
std::cerr << " * Sample Rate : " << std::setw(6) << in_samplerate << std::endl;

// Read audio data as float
std::vector<float> in_data( in_frames * in_channels );
infile_handle.read( in_data.data(), in_data.size() );
```

If you just want to use SoX on the command line and get text output, you can do something like this:

```
sox vocal2.wav -t f32 - | od -ve -An | more
```

Here I've specified an output of raw 32-bit float, and run it through GNU *od*.  It's a little frustrating that you can't tell *od* how many columns you want, but you can clean that up with other simple tools.  Have a look at the manpage for *od* if you want different sample encodings.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Is there any chance you could share your whole  C++ code? I have the code compiling apart from "verbose" which isn't defined - what exactly is the function of "verbose"?

Comment: I just dumped this out of my command-line app, figuring that it would be obvious that's irrelevant.  `verbose` was just set if I pass `-v` as a command line argument.  I've removed that from my answer.  I really don't see the need to post my full code, because it's huge and even more irrelevant to what you're asking.

Comment: That's fair enough, I got libsndfile doing what I wanted anyway (selecting a wav file and getting its frequency out) but I'd never come across the term verbose when it comes to coding. Thanks!

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski of course you are entitled to do that. Allow me to highlight that if you read the question more carefully, you'll see they wanted to get WAV amplitude in their C++ program and in fact found it annoying to do any kind of external file conversions. The fact is, SoX _does not_ provide any feature for doing what was being asked so I provided a couple of simple alternatives that were better fit for purpose. This may not fit your idealized view of what software engineering is about, but I'm afraid that is just reality. We often have to use solutions that we did not expect.

Answer (score 0):

A wav file consists of a trivial header plus a long list of 16 bit pcm samples.

Here's some code to read one, not quite sure of its development status.

```
#define WAVE_FORMAT_PCM 0x01
#define WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT  0x03
#define WAVE_FORMAT_ALAW    0x06  /*8 - bit ITU - T G.711 A - law */
#define WAVE_FORMAT_MULAW   0x07 /* 8 - bit ITU - T G.711 µ - law */
#define WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE 0xFFFE


typedef struct
{
    short format_tag;
    short channels;
    short block_align;
    short bits_per_sample;
    unsigned long format_length;
    unsigned long sample_rate;
    unsigned long avg_bytes_sec;

    unsigned long data_size;
    unsigned char *sound_buffer;
} WAV;

WAV *loadwav(const char* filename, int *err);
WAV *floadwav(FILE *fp, int *err);
void killwav(WAV *wav);

static void readformatchunk(FILE *fp, WAV *wav, int *err);
static void readdatachunk(FILE *fp, WAV *wav, int *err);
static void readunknownchunk(FILE *fp, int *err);
static double freadieee754(FILE *fp, int bigendian);
static float freadieee754f(FILE *fp, int bigendian);
static int fget16le(FILE *fp);
static long fget32le(FILE *fp);

WAV *loadwav16stereo(const char *filename, int *err)
{

}
WAV *loadwav(const char* filename, int *err)
{
    WAV *answer;
    FILE *fp;

    if (err)
        *err = 0;
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        *err = -2;
        return 0;
    }
    answer = floadwav(fp, err);
    fclose(fp);

    return answer;
}

WAV *floadwav(FILE *fp, int *err)
{
    short format_tag, channels, block_align, bits_per_sample;
    unsigned long format_length, sample_rate, avg_bytes_sec, i;

    unsigned char *sound_buffer;
    int data_size;

    WAV *answer = 0;
    unsigned char id[4];
    unsigned long size;

    if (err)
        *err = 0;

    answer = malloc(sizeof(WAV));
    if (!answer)
        goto out_of_memory;
    answer->sound_buffer = 0;

    fread(id, sizeof(unsigned char), 4, fp);

    if (strncmp(id, "RIFF", 4))
        goto parse_error;

    size = fget32le(fp);
    fread(id, sizeof(unsigned char), 4, fp);
    if (strncmp(id, "WAVE", 4))
        goto parse_error;

    while (1)
    {
        if (fread(id, sizeof(unsigned char), 4, fp) != 4)
            goto parse_error;
        if (!strncmp(id, "fmt ", 4))
        {
            readformatchunk(fp, answer, err);
            if (*err)
                goto parse_error;
        }
        else if (!strncmp(id, "data", 4))
        {
            readdatachunk(fp, answer, err);
            if (*err)
                goto parse_error;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }


    return answer;

parse_error:
    if (err)
        *err = -3;
    killwav(answer);
    return 0;
out_of_memory:
    if (err)
        *err = -1;
    killwav(answer);
    return 0;
}

void killwav(WAV *wav)
{
    if (wav)
    {
        free(wav->sound_buffer);
        free(wav);
    }
}

int wav_Nchannels(WAV *wav)
{
    return wav->channels;
}

int wav_samplerate(WAV *wav)
{
    return wav->sample_rate;
}

unsigned short *wav_samplesasshort(WAV *wav, long *Nsamples)
{
    unsigned short *answer = 0;
    long N;
    long i;

    if (wav->format_tag == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM && wav->bits_per_sample == 8)
    {
        N = wav->data_size;
        answer = malloc(N * sizeof(short));
        if (!answer)
            goto out_of_memory;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            answer[i] = (wav->sound_buffer[i] - 128) * 256;
        }
    }
    else if (wav->format_tag == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM && wav->bits_per_sample == 16)
    {
        short *sbuffer = (short *) wav->sound_buffer;
        N = wav->data_size/2;
        answer = malloc(N * sizeof(short));
        if (!answer)
            goto out_of_memory;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            answer[i] = sbuffer[i];
        }
    }
    else if (wav->format_tag == WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT && wav->bits_per_sample == 32)
    {
        float *fbuffer = (float *)wav->sound_buffer;
        N = wav->data_size / 4;
        answer = malloc(N * sizeof(short));
        if (!answer)
            goto out_of_memory;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            answer[i] = (short)(fbuffer[i] * SHRT_MAX);
        }
    }
    else if (wav->format_tag == WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT && wav->bits_per_sample == 32)
    {
        float *dbuffer = (float *)wav->sound_buffer;
        N = wav->data_size / 8;
        answer = malloc(N * sizeof(short));
        if (!answer)
            goto out_of_memory;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            answer[i] = (short)(dbuffer[i] * SHRT_MAX);
        }
    }
    if (Nsamples)
        *Nsamples = N;
    return answer;

out_of_memory:
    return 0;
}

static void readformatchunk(FILE *fp, WAV *wav, int *err)
{
    short format_tag, channels, block_align, bits_per_sample;
    unsigned long format_length, sample_rate, avg_bytes_sec, i;
    short cb_size = 0;
    short valid_bits_per_sample;
    unsigned long channel_mask;
    unsigned char guid[16];

    format_length = fget32le(fp);
    if (format_length < 16)
        goto parse_error;
    //fread(&format_tag, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    format_tag = fget16le(fp);
    //fread(&channels, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    channels = fget16le(fp);
    //fread(&sample_rate, sizeof(unsigned long), 1, fp);
    sample_rate = fget32le(fp);
    //fread(&avg_bytes_sec, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    avg_bytes_sec = fget32le(fp);
    //fread(&block_align, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    block_align = fget16le(fp);
    //fread(&bits_per_sample, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
    bits_per_sample = fget16le(fp);

    if (format_length > 16)
    {
        cb_size = fget16le(fp);
    }
    if (cb_size >= 22)
    {
        valid_bits_per_sample = fget16le(fp);
        channel_mask = fget32le(fp);
        fread(&guid, 1, 16, fp);

        cb_size -= 22;
        for (i = 0; i < cb_size; i++)
            fgetc(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < cb_size; i++)
            fgetc(fp);
    }
    wav->format_tag = format_tag;
    wav->channels = channels;
    wav->bits_per_sample = bits_per_sample;
    wav->sample_rate = sample_rate;

    return;
parse_error:
    *err = -1;
}

static void readdatachunk(FILE *fp, WAV *wav, int *err)
{
    unsigned long data_size;
    unsigned long i;
    unsigned char *sound_buffer;
    unsigned char *buff8;
    short *buff16;
    float *bufffloat;
    double *buffdouble;

    data_size = fget32le(fp);
    wav->data_size = data_size;
    if (wav->format_tag == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM && wav->bits_per_sample == 8)
    {
        buff8 = malloc(data_size);
        for (i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
        {
            buff8[i] = fgetc(fp);
        }
        wav->sound_buffer = buff8;
    }
    else if (wav->format_tag == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM && wav->bits_per_sample == 16)
    {
        buff16 = malloc(data_size/2 * sizeof(short));
        for (i = 0; i < data_size/2; i++)
        {
            buff16[i] = fget16le(fp);
        }
        wav->sound_buffer = buff16;
    }
    else if (wav->format_tag == WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT && wav->bits_per_sample == 32)
    {
        bufffloat = malloc(data_size / 4 * sizeof(float));
        for (i = 0; i < data_size / 4; i++)
        {
            bufffloat[i] = freadieee754f(fp, 0);
        }
        wav->sound_buffer = bufffloat;

    }
    else if (wav->format_tag == WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT && wav->bits_per_sample == 64)
    {
        buffdouble = malloc(data_size / 8 * sizeof(float));
        for (i = 0; i < data_size / 8; i++)
        {
            buffdouble[i] = freadieee754(fp, 0);
        }
        wav->sound_buffer = buffdouble;
    }
    return;
parse_error:
    *err = -3;
    return;
out_of_memory:
    *err = -1;
    return;
}

static void readunknownchunk(FILE *fp, int *err)
{
    unsigned long data_size;

    data_size = fget32le(fp);
    while (data_size--)
    {
        if (fgetc(fp) == EOF)
            goto parse_error;
    }
    return;
parse_error:
    *err = -3;
    return;
}

static int wav_is_16bitstereo(WAV *wav)
{

}

/*
* read a double from a stream in ieee754 format regardless of host
*  encoding.
*  fp - the stream
*  bigendian - set to if big bytes first, clear for little bytes
*              first
*
*/
static double freadieee754(FILE *fp, int bigendian)
{
    unsigned char buff[8];
    int i;
    double fnorm = 0.0;
    unsigned char temp;
    int sign;
    int exponent;
    double bitval;
    int maski, mask;
    int expbits = 11;
    int significandbits = 52;
    int shift;
    double answer;

    /* read the data */
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        buff[i] = fgetc(fp);
    /* just reverse if not big-endian*/
    if (!bigendian)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            temp = buff[i];
            buff[i] = buff[8 - i - 1];
            buff[8 - i - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    sign = buff[0] & 0x80 ? -1 : 1;
    /* exponet in raw format*/
    exponent = ((buff[0] & 0x7F) << 4) | ((buff[1] & 0xF0) >> 4);

    /* read inthe mantissa. Top bit is 0.5, the successive bits half*/
    bitval = 0.5;
    maski = 1;
    mask = 0x08;
    for (i = 0; i < significandbits; i++)
    {
        if (buff[maski] & mask)
            fnorm += bitval;

        bitval /= 2.0;
        mask >>= 1;
        if (mask == 0)
        {
            mask = 0x80;
            maski++;
        }
    }
    /* handle zero specially */
    if (exponent == 0 && fnorm == 0)
        return 0.0;

    shift = exponent - ((1 << (expbits - 1)) - 1); /* exponent = shift + bias */
    /* nans have exp 1024 and non-zero mantissa */
    if (shift == 1024 && fnorm != 0)
        return sqrt(-1.0);
    /*infinity*/
    if (shift == 1024 && fnorm == 0)
    {

#ifdef INFINITY
        return sign == 1 ? INFINITY : -INFINITY;
#endif
        return  (sign * 1.0) / 0.0;
    }
    if (shift > -1023)
    {
        answer = ldexp(fnorm + 1.0, shift);
        return answer * sign;
    }
    else
    {
        /* denormalised numbers */
        if (fnorm == 0.0)
            return 0.0;
        shift = -1022;
        while (fnorm < 1.0)
        {
            fnorm *= 2;
            shift--;
        }
        answer = ldexp(fnorm, shift);
        return answer * sign;
    }
}


static float freadieee754f(FILE *fp, int bigendian)
{
    unsigned long buff = 0;
    unsigned long buff2 = 0;
    unsigned long mask;
    int sign;
    int exponent;
    int shift;
    int i;
    int significandbits = 23;
    int expbits = 8;
    double fnorm = 0.0;
    double bitval;
    double answer;

    for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
        buff = (buff << 8) | fgetc(fp);
    if (!bigendian)
    {
        for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
        {
            buff2 <<= 8;
            buff2 |= (buff & 0xFF);
            buff >>= 8;
        }
        buff = buff2;
    }

    sign = (buff & 0x80000000) ? -1 : 1;
    mask = 0x00400000;
    exponent = (buff & 0x7F800000) >> 23;
    bitval = 0.5;
    for (i = 0; i<significandbits; i++)
    {
        if (buff & mask)
            fnorm += bitval;
        bitval /= 2;
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    if (exponent == 0 && fnorm == 0.0)
        return 0.0f;
    shift = exponent - ((1 << (expbits - 1)) - 1); /* exponent = shift + bias */

    if (shift == 128 && fnorm != 0.0)
        return (float)sqrt(-1.0);
    if (shift == 128 && fnorm == 0.0)
    {
#ifdef INFINITY
        return sign == 1 ? INFINITY : -INFINITY;
#endif
        return (sign * 1.0f) / 0.0f;
    }
    if (shift > -127)
    {
        answer = ldexp(fnorm + 1.0, shift);
        return (float)answer * sign;
    }
    else
    {
        if (fnorm == 0.0)
        {
            return 0.0f;
        }
        shift = -126;
        while (fnorm < 1.0)
        {
            fnorm *= 2;
            shift--;
        }
        answer = ldexp(fnorm, shift);
        return (float)answer * sign;
    }
}

static int fget16le(FILE *fp)
{
    int c1, c2;

    c1 = fgetc(fp);
    c2 = fgetc(fp);

    return ((c2 ^ 128) - 128) * 256 + c1;
}

static long fget32le(FILE *fp)
{
    int c1, c2, c3, c4;

    c1 = fgetc(fp);
    c2 = fgetc(fp);
    c3 = fgetc(fp);
    c4 = fgetc(fp);
    return ((c4 ^ 128) - 128) * 256 * 256 * 256 + c3 * 256 * 256 + c2 * 256 + c1;
}


void wavfilemain(void)
{
    int err;
    WAV *wav = loadwav("C:\\Users\\Malcolm\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\ANSIScratch\\ANSIScratch\\LaserBlast.wav", &err);
    short *samples;
    long N;
    long i;

    printf("here %p\n", wav);
    printf("%d fmt %d bits %d channels %d\n", wav->sample_rate, wav->format_tag, wav->bits_per_sample, wav->channels);
    samples = wav_samplesasshort(wav, &N);

    killwav(wav);
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to do it through SoX as it's relatively lightweight and only uses one line of code for the conversion (and I know that it works)